# Searching nth-level friends in neo4j.rb in bi-directional relationship graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, bidirectional, neo4j.rb, bidirectional-relation

I have a User class defined as below

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  include Neo4j::Timestamps
  property :user_id, type: Integer, constraint: :unique
  property :max_friends_count, type: Integer, default: 5
  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  has_many :out, :followings, model_class: :GraphUser, rel_class: :GraphRel, unique: true
  has_many :in, :followers, model_class: :GraphUser, rel_class: :GraphRel, unique: true
end
```

I have created `user1` and `user2` with user_id 1 and 2 respectively.

And then I dis search followings of followings using
`user1.followings(rel_length: 2)`. But the result come out as `user1` itself because both `user1` and `user2` are following each other.

I have tried `order(:breadth_first)` and other methods to exclude the nodes that have already been visited. I might not have done enough research but does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you might want to use the `id_property`.  If you use a `property` for `user_id` and set `constraint: :unique` you'll still have the automatically generated `uuid` property.  That may be what you want, but just a heads up.  Here's the documentation for `id_property`:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Unique-IDs

To your question, your code generates Cypher similar to this (I needed to change the `model_class` and `rel_class` options):

```
MATCH user15573
WHERE (ID(user15573) = {ID_user15573})
MATCH user15573-[rel1:`FOLLOWS`*2]->(result_followings:`User`)
```

In a single `MATCH` clause in Cypher, Neo4j will make sure that the same relationship isn't traversed more than once for a single path traversal.  But as you said if they are following each other that means that it can follow the other relationship to go back to the original user.  In that can you'd need to exclude the original user from the potential results:

```
MATCH user15573
WHERE (ID(user15573) = {ID_user15573})
MATCH user15573-[rel1:`FOLLOWS`*2]->(result_followings:`User`)
WHERE result_followings <> user15573
```

In Ruby this would be:

```
user1.as(:source).followings(:target, nil, rel_length: 2).where('source <> target')
```